# how to call a custom PDF plug-in in dita-ot -3.0

Tags: pdf, plugins, dita-ot

I am a non-programmer TW, thank you first for your help, if any.(*￣︶￣)

I custom a PDF plugin by using *http://dita-generator.elovirta.com/*.
and use *dita --install* command to install the plugin .zip file. I check the *plugins* file in default dita-ot-3.0 directory, the plugin has been successfully installed.
Here is the question: how can i call the custom PDF plugin when outputting PDF from a ditamap file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined a name for the transformation in the last step. Open the `plugin.xml` and look up the transtype name from the extension point `dita.transtype.print`.

```
<feature extension="dita.transtype.print" value="NAME_OF_YOUR_TRANSTYPE"/>
```

Then call `dita --input your.fitamap --format NAME_OF_YOUR_TRANSTYPE`.